# Include captions

Tags: images, metabox, captions

I'm using the [Meta Box plugin](http://www.deluxeblogtips.com/meta-box/), everything works fine. I'm using it to create gallery function on some custom post type, and I'm able to display the uploaded images using this code:

```
global $wpdb;
$meta = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'meta_key', false );

if ( ! is_array( $meta ) )
    $meta = ( array ) $meta;

if ( ! empty( $meta ) )
{
    $meta = implode( ',', $meta );
    $images = $wpdb->get_col( "SELECT ID FROM {$wpdb->posts}
    WHERE post_type = 'attachment'
    AND ID IN ( {$meta} )
    ORDER BY menu_order ASC" );
    foreach ( $images as $att )
    {
        // Get image's source based on size, can be 'thumbnail', 'medium', 'large', 'full' or registed post thumbnails sizes
        $src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $att, 'full' );
        $src = $src[0];
        // Show image
        echo "<img src='{$src}' />";
    }
}
```

The images are shown, but I want to also display the captions from each picture.
How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. <sup>st</sup> Note:

   ```
   // Prepare the code for safety
   $images = $wpdb->get_col( $wpdb->prepare( "
       SELECT ID FROM %s
       WHERE post_type = 'attachment'
       AND ID IN ( %s )
       ORDER BY menu_order ASC
   ", $wpdb->posts, $meta ) );
   ```
2. <sup>nd</sup> Note: Look into what you already got:

   ```
   // Inside the foreach loop
   echo '<pre>'; var_dump( $att ); echo '<pre>';
   ```
3. <sup>rd</sup> Note: [`wp_get_attachment_metadata()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_metadata) gives you meta data. Just drop the post ID in there.

Comment: In this case: Edit my answer to leave a complete sample for later readers :)

Comment: Hello kaiser, it seems that the solution I found duplicated some images randomly :( Also, using wp_get_attachment_metadata(), the caption displayed was the one from the Exif file, not from the Media Library item. Will try to find the solution and will be posted here. Regards.